# jquery search element with text, hide another

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I search an element for a text string and hide another?
For example: if a div contains the name of John, the div that contains the name of George should be hidden.

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div class="test">George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "div:contains('John')" )."div:contains('George')".hide();
});
```

Or shouldn't I use jQuery contains in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You jQuery is incorrect by all means. You need to use :

```
if($("div:contains('John')").length){
    $("div:contains('George')").hide();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("div:contains('John')").length){
    $("div:contains('George')").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's great Angkit. Why is the .length property in your syntax?

Comment: @ElsdenIep `lenght` is to check if exists `div` containing "John". Lenght equals 0 if `<div>John Resig</div>` not exist.

Comment: Thanks Ankit. I have ticked your answer. Is it possible to only hide a part of the string in the div that contains George? E.g. only hide his surname?

Comment: The content of `div` that has `George Martin` is not surrounded by any other elements like `<span class='fname'>GeorgeM</span><span class='lname'> Martin</span>` so that will not be possible. However, you can replace the text `GeorgeM` from that div if you do not want that value to appear again on the HTML @ElsdenIep

Answer (score 1):

You are so close!

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).next("div:contains('George')").hide();
```

use **Next** to find the next element matching.
Source: https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: That's a nice solution as well. Would it be possible to specify all divs that contain 'George' instead of only using the next div?

Comment: That is not a relevant question of mine: I have tested the code and it appears that all divs containing 'George' are hidden. So better question is: how could I appoint certain divs only (e.g. by using their class or ID)?

Comment: I have found that. Following only hides div class="test": $(document).ready(function () {
$( "div:contains('John')" ).next("div.test:contains('George')").hide();
});

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `siblings` instead of `next`, because `next` won't work if **George** will be before **John**

```
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div:contains('John')").siblings("div:contains('George')").hide(); // hide all "Georde"
   // $("div:contains('John')").siblings("div:contains('George')").first().hide(); // hide only first "Georde"
});
```

Comment: Good thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$("div:contains(George)").toggle($("div:contains('John')").length)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div:contains(George)").toggle($("div:contains('John')").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div:contains('John')").next("div:contains('George')").hide();
```